# I have a P0172 code Ford Focus, 2005- then I did a freeze frame; what does the following data mean?

Tags: ford, focus, rough-idle

My ford focus 2005, Zx3 has been acting up running real rough turning off from time to time, I bought an OBD2 scanner and the P0172 code came up. I changed the fuel filter and the car ran good for about a day or so, then the idling issue started again. I'm wondering if you can tell me what this data means. I'm getting a Too Rich Bank 1. I know I have to do a smoke test, but I'm concerned about how to read this data. I researched the fuel pressure, and supposedly Ford's Focus fuel pressure varies from 25-65PSI for fuel pressure, i'm idling and the fuel is at 39.7, or I think frp = Fuel Rate Pressure. **Can you help me read this data as I have too much fuel, and not enough air.**

```
View Freeze Frame 
DTCFRZF           p0172 
Load PCT %        36.5
ETC(f)            149
Shift1%           36.7
LONGFT1(%)        -26.6
MAP(inHg)         8.5
RPM (/min)        926 
VSS(mph)          0
SPARKADV          8
IAF (f)           70
MAF(lb/min)       .464 
TP(%)             17.3 
AIRSTAT           OFF 
O2BS1             .180 
SHRTFTB1S1        35.9
O2B1S2            .645
SHRTFTB1S2        99.2 
O2B2S1(V)         0.00
RUNTM(SEC)        83 
FRP (PSI)         39.7
EGR_PTC(%)        .8
FLI(%)            31.80
WARM UPS          2 
CLR DIST (MILE)   12 
BARO(IN HG)       29.4
CATEMP11          942.26
LOAD ABS          18 
EQ RAT            .999
TP_R (%)          0.00
AAT (f)           61
```

Comment: Was it running rough when you did the freeze frame? Was the engine fully warm? An instantaneous set of readings may not be very helpful...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix Check Engine Light (OBDII code: P0172)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/37821/how-to-fix-check-engine-light-obdii-code-p0172). The only thing I'd add to the answers there is the rough idle and stalling makes a vacuum leak likely, and that's a known issue with the Focus.

Comment: @SolarMike It was running rough, and yes.

Comment: @GdD- based on this post:  

-Too much fuel is being injected (clean/new fuel filter) 
-Not enough air is coming in (maybe it's a faulty reading from the mass airflow sensor, filter reading states in good health) 
-There isn't enough spark to burn the fuel completely
-The oxygen sensor is reading incorrectly, and everything is actually fine (new o2 sensor). I think I'm left with one valid conclusion and maybe I have a faulty airflow meter sensor which I may need to clean. I think I need to do a vacuum test to find the vacuum leak if there is one.